# AttributeError: 'CartPoleEnv' object has no attribute 'seed' when on gym 0.26.2 and python 3.10.8

Tags: python, openai-gym

I'm trying to seed randomness in the `cart-pole` environment CartPole-v1 in gym, but there is no seed attribute. I've made sure gym and python are current and looked through documentation but not found anything. Please help.

Here is what I've tried:

```
env = gym.make('CartPole-v1')
env.seed(0)
```

I expected that this code would run with no issues, but I actually came out with this error:

> AttributeError: 'CartPoleEnv' object has no attribute 'seed'

Answer (score 3):

The `seed` is passed through at `env.reset()`:

```py
import gym

env = gym.make('CartPole-v1')
obs, info = env.reset(seed=0)

obs, info
>>> [ 0.01369617 -0.02302133 -0.04590265 -0.04834723] {}
```

The environment always has to be reset before you can make a first `step`. In this `reset`, you can pass in the `seed` and any additional `options` (if there are any).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. It was resolved by install an older version of `gym`:

`pip install gym==0.25.2`